# Wordpress and the syntax

Tags: wordpress

```
$users = get_users(array('role' => '','orderby' => 'meta_value','meta_key' => 'description'
       ,'order' => 'ASC','meta_query' => array(array('orderby' => 'meta_value'
       ,'meta_key'=> 'nummer','order' => 'ASC', ))));
```

Working on a website and need to sort players by numbers and position they play in floorball. The code work separately but not together can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific please. Anyway you have a comma in addition at the end.

```
$users = get_users(array('role' => '','orderby' => 'meta_value','meta_key' => 'description','order' => 'ASC','meta_query' => array(array('orderby' => 'meta_value','meta_key' => 'nummer','order' => 'ASC'))));
```

Comment: The two functions works separately but not together. I just want them to be in one function total as i have tried in the code example above.